# printing items in a list represented by bit list

Tags: python, list

I have this problem on writing a python function which takes a bit list as input and prints the items represented by this bit list.

so the question is on Knapsack and it is a relatively simple and straightforward one as I'm new to the python language too.

so technically the items can be named in a list [1,2,3,4] which corresponds to Type 1, Type 2, Type 3 and etc but we won't be needing the "type". the problem is, i represented the solution in a bit list [0,1,1,1] where 0 means not taken and 1 means taken. in another words, item of type 1 is not taken but the rest are taken, as represented in the bit list i wrote.

now we are required to write a python function which takes the bit list as input and prints the item corresponding to it in which in this case i need the function to print out [2,3,4] leaving out the 1 since it is 0 by bit list. any help on this? it is a 2 mark question but i still couldn't figure it out.

```
def printItems(l):
for x in range(len(l)):
    if x == 0:
        return False
    elif x == 1:
        return l
```

i tried something like that but it is wrong. much appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the zip function that takes two tiers Lee and returns them in pairs:

```
for bit_item, item in zip(bit_list, item_list):
    if bit_item:
        print item
```

Or if you need a list rather than printing them, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[item for bit_item, item in zip(bit_list, item_list) if bit_item]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it using *list comprehension* with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) as:

```
>>> my_list = [0, 1, 1, 1]
>>> taken_list = [i for i, item in enumerate(my_list, 1) if item]
>>> taken_list             # by default start with 0  ^
[2, 3, 4]
```

---

Alternatively, in case you do not need any in-built function and want to create your own function, you may modify your code as:

```
def printItems(l):
    new_list = []
    for x in range(len(l)):
        if l[x] == 1:
            new_list.append(x+1) # "x+1" because index starts with `0` and you need position
    return new_list
```

Sample run:

```
>>> printItems([0, 1, 1, 1])
[2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.compress` for a quick solution:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.compress(itertools.count(1), [0, 1, 1, 1]))
[2, 3, 4]
```

The reason your solution doesn't work is because you are using `return` in your function, where you need to use `print`, and make sure you are iterating over your list correctly. In this case, `enumerate` simplifies things, but there are many similar approaches that would work:

```
>>> def print_items(l):
...     for i,b in enumerate(l,1):
...         if b:
...             print(i)
... 
>>> print_items([0,1,1,1])
2
3
4
>>>
```